# Wordpress font suddenly changed, don't know why

Tags: css, wordpress, macos, google-chrome, fonts

Today I noticed that font on my website [mstem.net](https://mstem.net) changed. I don't know why yet this font changed. In my main CSS file I have imported Google Fonts like:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,900');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900');
```

I checked for CSS code from Google Chrome Console and I noticed there is CSS rule added like:

```
font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
```

I don't know where this line of code came from. When I uncheck it font comes back to normal.

Could you write me how to disable this CSS rule permanently?

I must add that I use Google Chrome Browser at Macbook with OSX 10.13.6.

Thank you for your help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

That CSS is coming from bootstrap.

In your header you have

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='my-styles-css'  href='https://mstem.net/wp-content/themes/wp-learn-marcelo/css/my-styles.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
...
...
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css-css'  href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Move your `my-styles` CSS below bootstrap for it to take precedence.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css-css'  href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='my-styles-css'  href='https://mstem.net/wp-content/themes/wp-learn-marcelo/css/my-styles.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Comment: Hello @abney317. The header in WordPress is added automatically as I remember. Scripts are added in functions.php file in WordPress and they are added by this line of code in header.php file: <?php wp_head(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve that problem.

I installed Insert Header and Footers WordPress Plugin and paste in the header section this Google Fonts code:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;900&family=Oswald:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

I looked up to a file which was the problem and I found out that problem was with the normilze.css file. I don't know if it was added with the newest WP version automatically or in some other way but it has broken my website.